# How to extract separate parts of a string with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex that can process the following:

- abc
- abc-def

where the -def part is optional.

I'm wanting to get capture groups for the "abc", and optional "def" part.

I've tried this (in Javascript) but can't seem to figure out the optional part:

```
/^(.*)+(-(.*))?$/
```

It matches both examples but the optional part is contained in the first capture group. This should be simple, but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `/^([^-]+)(-(.*))?$/`. One issue is that the first `+` is outside of the capture group which means it'll only match the last character. Secondly, the `.*` is greedy and will match a `-`, gobbling all the way to the end of the line.

Runnable example:

```js
console.log("abc-def".match(/^([^-]*)(-(.*))?$/));
console.log("abc".match(/^([^-]*)(-(.*))?$/));
```

You may not need to capture the substring starting with `-`, in which case `/^([^-]*)(?:-(.*))?$/` could work.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, try a `?` to make the expression [lazy](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html).

```
/^(.*?)(-(.*))?$/
```